# Different output with backtracking and DP

Tags: c++, c++14

I am using DP to solve a problem but the solution without DP i.e. just backtracking gives the correct output while the same code just with DP gives wrong output.Can't figure out why.

link to question- https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=1278

Here is the code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int lli;
#define oo 1000000007;
lli dp[12][1005];
int a[10][1005];
int n;
lli calc(int alt,int i){
    if(dp[alt][i] != -1) {
        return dp[alt][i];
    }
    if(i==n && alt==0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(alt>9 || alt<0 || i==n) {
        return oo;
    }
    return dp[alt][i] = min(
        min(
            lli(30) - a[alt][i] + calc(alt  ,i+1),
            lli(20) - a[alt][i] + calc(alt-1,i+1)
        ),
        lli(60) - a[alt][i] + calc(alt+1,i+1)
    );
}
int main(){
    int t;
    string bl;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        getline(cin,bl);
        memset(dp,-1,sizeof dp);
        scanf("%d",&n);
        n = n/100;
        for(int i=9; i>=0; i--) {
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
                scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        lli ans = calc(0,0);
        printf("%lld\n",ans);
        if(t!=0) printf("\n");
    }
}
```

the input is

```
1
400
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 9 9 1
1 -9 -9 1
```

The correct output is 120.

Comment: ahh..i'll indent

Comment: No one wants to look for bugs in your algorithm, especially if your code is messy and hardly understandable. Please create a minimal, complete and verifiable example so we can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: _"gives the correct output while the same code just with DP gives wrong output"_ So... Define "correct" and "wrong", with example input and output data.

Comment: @underscore_d i have already provided input and correct output.

Comment: Have you stepped through this code with a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(dp[alt][i] != -1) {
    return dp[alt][i];
}

lli(20) - a[alt][i] + calc(alt-1,i+1)
```

You are just (un)lucky the program didn't straight out crash on you!

For `alt == -1`, you read just some random garbage on the recursion. You are reading random values from outside the `dp` array.

Switch them like this and it should work (or at least have defined behavior):

```
if(i==n && alt==0) {
    return 0;
}
if(alt>9 || alt<0 || i==n) {
    return oo;
}
if(dp[alt][i] != -1) {
    return dp[alt][i];
}
```

---

Either way, your approach simply doesn't work. You are traversing depth first (finds any path!), but traversal order must be broad first to find the shortest route.

That means you can't use recursion like this, but must rather iterate by `alt` in the inner, and `i` in the outer loop. Then you can fill in your path field step by step.

---

Naive dynamic programming like this isn't the best solution for this task. You should better treat it as an directed, weighted graph, and apply standard Dijkstra. With your method, you will compute (without need) all possible routes.

Comment: I get all your points but for the one that it uses garbage value.. I mean either it has - 1 stored in DP array or the value assigned.

Comment: @abhihacker02 You are reading outside the DP array. That is neither `-1` or any other value you have control over, but completely unrelated memory. If you had written to that memory, it would have had unpredictable consequences.

Comment: You just changed your answer.. It was when alt ==0 first.. Thanks anyways. Silly mistake.